# Add text box on click on Add Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5

I am working on laravel framework here i need when user click on Add more button the textbox add above on button. I need 18 textbox when user reached to 18th Textbox it will give alert.I don't know how to add. I am new in jquery and javascript. Can anyone help me

Here is the screenshot:-[image]

Here is my Html Code:-

```
<div>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
        <div class="sign-btn signup-page">
        <button class="btn btn-info sign-bttn">Add More</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where is your javascript code?

Comment: i don't know how to code jquery of this part. thats y i m asking madalin

Answer (score 3):

Make array of `name` to get values of each name and the code looks like,

```js
$(function() {
  var len = 4; // for testing purpose I am using 4 you can change it to 18
  $('.sign-bttn').on('click', function() {
    if($('#name-container-list .name-list').length==len){
       alert("You can't add more");
       return false;
    }
    $clone = $('#name-container-list .name-list:first').clone();
    $clone.find('input').val(''); // empty the new clone field
    $(this).parent('div').before($clone);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="name-container-list">
  <div class="name-list">
    <input type="text" name="name[]" class="form-control" />
  </div>
  <div class="sign-btn signup-page">
    <button class="btn btn-info sign-bttn">Add More</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How will we get the each text box value

Comment: Make `name` as array of fields like `name[]`.

Comment: Thanks  rohan. i run your code but now when i click on addmore button when i add third textbox it will alert me "you can't add more" but my length is 4 .

Comment: Firstly, you didn't try anything and don't try to understand the logic which is given on SO. It is total length of `name[]` and you can change it according to your requirement and in this case the `len` should be `5`.

Answer (score 1):

This might help,

```js
$('.sign-bttn').click(function(e) {
  $('.text-boxes').prepend('<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-boxes">
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
        <div class="sign-btn signup-page">
        <button class="btn btn-info sign-bttn">Add More</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Html:

```
<div id="divContain">
  <div id='divText'>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
  </div>

  <div class="sign-btn signup-page">
    <button class="btn btn-info sign-bttn">Add More</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Your JQuery:

```
 var maxField = 18;
 var fieldHTML = ' <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">'; //New input field html 
 var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1
 $('.btn-info').click(function() { //Once add button is clicked
   if (x < maxField) { //Check maximum number of input fields
     x++; //Increment field counter
     $('#divText').append(fieldHTML); // Add field html
   }
   else
   {

   alert('No more text box :)');
   }
 });
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shree/z0a63rk3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){


$('.sign-bttn').click(function(e) {

if($('input[name="name"]').length < 18)
{
$('.text-boxes').prepend('<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value='+ ($('input[name="name"]').length + 1) +'>');
}
else
{
alert("reached 18 TextBoxes.............")
}
});


    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="text-boxes">
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
        <div class="sign-btn signup-page">
        <button class="btn btn-info sign-bttn">Add More</button>
        </div>
</div>


        </body>


    </body>
    </html>
```